# How to fix my promise return here for this function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I have an array of `tags` which may contain up to 3 items.

Next I pass `tags` into my `getTagQuotes` function and am trying to set a promise variable to it. **Right now I'm getting promise is undefined.**

[image]

```
// If there are tags, the wait for promise here:
if (tags.length > 0) {
    var promise = getTagQuotes(tags).then(function() {
        console.log('promise =',promise);

        for (var i=0; i<tweetArrayObjsContainer.length; i++) {
            chartObj.chartData.push(tweetArrayObjsContainer[i]);
        }

        chartDirective = ScopeFactory.getScope('chart');
        chartDirective.nvd3.drawChart(chartObj.chartData);
    });
}
else {
    chartDirective = ScopeFactory.getScope('chart');
    chartDirective.nvd3.drawChart(chartObj.chartData);
}
```

^ The goal above is to make sure that arrays in `tweetArrayObjsContainer` have been filled and pushed into `chartObj.chartData` before I draw my `nvd3` chart.

Below is my `getTagQuotes` function which does another loop through the tags (up to 3) and calls another service `GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol` which makes the actual API call to retrieve data.

I have code which checks if the we're on the final loop step, then calls the `formatTagData` function.

Inside `formatTagData` is where I fill the `tweetArrayObjsContainer`.

```
// Check for and GET tag data:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getTagQuotes(tags) {
    console.log('getTagQuotes called with',tags);
    var deferred   = $q.defer(); // <- setting $q.defer here
    var url        = 'app/api/social/twitter/volume/';

    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        var loopStep = i;
        rawTagData   = [];

        GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol(url+tags[i].term_id)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                rawTagData.push(data);

                if (loopStep === (rawTagData.length - 1)) {
                    // formatTagData fills the tweetArrayObjsContainer with data:
                    formatTagData(rawTagData);
                    deferred.resolve(); // <-- last step, so resolve
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                return 'error in returning tweet data';
            });
    }

    function formatTagData(rawData) {
        tweetArrayObjsContainer = [];

        for (var i=0; i<rawData.length; i++) {
            var data_array = [];
            var loopNum = i;

            _(rawData[i].frequency_counts).reverse().value();

            for (var j=0; j<rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts.length; j++) {
                var data_obj = {};
                rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts[j].start_epoch = addZeroes(rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts[j].start_epoch);
                data_obj.x = rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts[j].start_epoch;
                data_obj.y = rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts[j].tweets;
                data_array.push(data_obj);
            }

            var tweetArrayObj = {
                "key"    : "Quantity"+(i+1),
                "type"   : "area",
                "yAxis"  : 1,
                "color"  : tagColorArray[i],
                "values" : data_array
            };

            tweetArrayObjsContainer.push(tweetArrayObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the point *entirely* of promises!

Comment: In your `getTagQuotes` function you are not returning any promise. For this reason is undefined when you check it. It's better if you read some documentation about "promises", for example [MDN Promise page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: @jamiec Promises tell a function to wait till something is returned before continuing along a chain, or just continuing correct?

Comment: No, not at all. there is no waiting involved. Promises provide a method to supply a callback which should be actioned when the asynchronous action completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getTagQuotes` function should return a promise with the `$q` service, [check it out](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

It should look like this:

```
function getTagQuotes(tags) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    (...)
    // When the action is finished here, call resolve:
    deferred.resolve();
    (...)

    // And in the end, return the promise
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And finally, in your main code, you'll do:

```
var promise = getTagQuotes(tags).then(function(){
    console.log('promise =',promise);
    // Fill chartObj with tweet data arrays
    (...)
});
```

Comment: `.promise` is a property not a function - should have no parentheses

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on the `var promise = getTagQuotes(tags)` line.. will post a gist in a bit

Comment: Ah! I forgot to return `return GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol`

Comment: You cannot return it. If you do so the for loop is worthless and you'll return always the first call.

Comment: @FernandoPinheiro thanks! Yeah I just found that problem out... trying to figure out how to return promises while using a for loop. I found `promise.all` however it isn't working as expected, will post a new question soon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998045/how-to-return-promise-after-for-loop-is-complete I tried `all` but not sure how to write it for a for loop correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This function has no return statement.

```
function getTagQuotes(tags)
```