# How to return single promise after for loop (which produces a promise on every iteration) is complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, promise, angular-promise

I have a problem with my promise return code, I have a function `getTagQuotes` which contains a for loop which can make multiple calls an API to return data into an array.

How my code for this begins below:

```
// If there are tags, then wait for promise here:
if (tags.length > 0) {

    // Setting promise var to getTagQuotes:
    var promise = getTagQuotes(tags).then(function() {
        console.log('promise =',promise);

        // This array should contain 1-3 tags:
        console.log('tweetArrayObjsContainer =',tweetArrayObjsContainer);

        // Loop through to push array objects into chartObj:
        for (var i=0; i<tweetArrayObjsContainer.length; i++) {
            chartObj.chartData.push(tweetArrayObjsContainer[i]);
        }

        // Finally draw the chart:
        chartDirective = ScopeFactory.getScope('chart');
        chartDirective.nvd3.drawChart(chartObj.chartData);
    });
}
```

My getTagQuotes function with the promise return:

```
function getTagQuotes(tags) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); // setting the defer
    var url      = 'app/api/social/twitter/volume/';

    // My for loop, which only returns ONCE, even if there are 3 tags
    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        var loopStep = i;
        rawTagData   = [];

        // The return statement
        return GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol(url+tags[i].term_id)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                rawTagData.push(data);

                // One the last loop, call formatTagData
                // which fills the tweetArrayObjsContainer Array
                if (loopStep === (rawTagData.length - 1)) {
                    formatTagData(rawTagData);
                    deferred.resolve();
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            });
    }

    function formatTagData(rawData) {

        for (var i=0; i<rawData.length; i++) {
            var data_array = [];
            var loopNum = i;

            for (var j=0; j<rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts.length; j++) {
                var data_obj = {};
                data_obj.x = rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts[j].start_epoch;
                data_obj.y = rawData[loopNum].frequency_counts[j].tweets;
                data_array.push(data_obj);
            }

            var tweetArrayObj = {
                "key" : "Quantity"+(loopNum+1), "type" : "area", "yAxis" : 1, "values" : data_array
            };

            tweetArrayObjsContainer.push(tweetArrayObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Take notice of this line

```
return GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol(url+tags[i].term_id)
```

it's inside my for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++)
```

Everything works great if I only have to loop through once. However as soon as there is another tag (up to 3) it still only returns the first loop/data. It does not wait till the for loop is done. Then return the promise. So my `tweetArrayObjsContainer` always only has the first tag.

Comment: The `return` inside the for loop returns from the entire `getTagQuotes` function. `return` will return from the current function, doesn't matter if you are in for loop or while loop or whatever.

Comment: I'm played around with this, if I remove return from `getTagQuotes` then I get `.then of function undefined` error on `getTagQuotes(tags).then(function()`

Comment: Of course, because you then returned nothing. Looks like you have 3 items, all of which return promises. And you want to wait for all promises to complete before taking an action.

Comment: You should return deferred.promise; instead of GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues:

1. you didn't return the deferred promise from the `getTagQuotes` method.
2. you were looking at `i` to see if you were through the loop, and the for loop is already completed (`i == (tags.length - 1)`) before the first success is even called.
3. you called `return` in the first iteration of the loop so that you didn't even get to the 2nd item.

Here's corrected code (didn't test it yet)

```
function getTagQuotes(tags) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); // setting the defer
    var url      = 'app/api/social/twitter/volume/';
    var tagsComplete = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        rawTagData   = [];
        GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol(url+tags[i].term_id)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                rawTagData.push(data);
                tagsComplete++;

                if (tagsComplete === tags.length) {
                    formatTagData(rawTagData);
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the solution! :D my `tweetArrayObjsContainer` is being filled, then after promise, it's pushed into `chartObj.chartData` then I can draw my chart.

Answer (score 2):

`return deferred.promise;` should be the return value of your function, not the `GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol()`, because that's what you intend to promisify.

Your problem is that you are calling several `GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol()`, and then you need to merge all those async calls to resolve your promise. In order to do that, you should promisify just one `GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol()` call:

```
function promisifiedTweetVol(rawTagData, urlStuff) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); // setting the defer

    GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol(urlStuff)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            rawTagData.push(data);

            // One the last loop, call formatTagData
            // which fills the tweetArrayObjsContainer Array
            if (loopStep === (rawTagData.length - 1)) {
                formatTagData(rawTagData);
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And then call each promise in a loop and return the promise that resolves when all promises are completed:

```
function getTagQuotes(tags) {
    var url      = 'app/api/social/twitter/volume/';
    var promises = [];

    // My for loop, which only returns ONCE, even if there are 3 tags
    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        var loopStep = if;
        rawTagData   = [];

        promises.push( promisifiedTweetVol(rawTagData, url+tags[i].term_id) );
    }

    // ...

    return $.when(promises);
}
```

There are a few more issues with your code, but you should be able to get this working with my tip.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like it's similar to Ben's I'm having trouble with another solution, will try both of yours here in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should return an array of promises here, which means that you should change getTagsQuotes like this:

```
function getTagQuotes(tags) {

    var url      = 'app/api/social/twitter/volume/',
        promises = [];

    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {

       promises.push( GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol( url+tags[i].term_id ) );

    }

    return promises;
}
```

And then loop through this promises like this:

```
if (tags.length > 0) {

    var promises = getTagQuotes(tags);

    promises.map( function( promise ) {

         promise.then( function( data ) { 

            //Manipulate data here

         });

    });
}
```

**Edit:** In case you want all promises to be finished as outlined in the comment you should do this:

```
if (tags.length > 0) {

    Promise.all( getTagQuotes(tags) ).then( function( data ) { 

        //Manipulate data here

    });
}
```

**Edit**: Full data manipulation:

```
Promise.all( getTagQuotes(tags) ).then( function( allData ) {

allData.map( function( data, dataIndex ){

    var rawData = data.data,
        dataLength = rawData.frequency_counts.length,
        j = 0,
        tweetArrayObj = {
            // "key"    : "Quantity"+(i+1),
            // "color"  : tagColorArray[i],
            "key"    : "Quantity",
            "type"   : "area",
            "yAxis"  : 1,
            "values" : []
        };

    for ( j; j < dataLength; j++ ) {

        rawData.frequency_counts[j].start_epoch = addZeroes( rawData.frequency_counts[j].start_epoch );

        tweetArrayObj.values.push( { x:rawData.frequency_counts[j].start_epoch, y:rawData.frequency_counts[j].tweets  } );

    }

    tweetArrayObjsContainer.push( tweetArrayObj );

});

for ( var i= 0,length = tweetArrayObjsContainer.length; i < length; i++ ) {

    chartObj.chartData.push( tweetArrayObjsContainer[ i ] );

}

chartDirective = ScopeFactory.getScope('chart');
chartDirective.nvd3.drawChart(chartObj.chartData);

});
```

Comment: In this case you should remove the deferred promise

Comment: Ah brilliant! Trying this now

Comment: This doesn't solve it. He wants to run *one* block of code, after *all* the promises have returned.

Comment: It's easy to change the code to accomodate to that, but just in case i added the solution to that also

Comment: Still working on it, the code in the function `formatTagData` has to be run up to 3 times. I've since moved that out and into the `promise.then( function( data ) { ` line

Comment: i could help you if i knew what you want to do with the data, it is just not very clear to me

Comment: Sorry I wish I could post a plunkr with this, but I can't without real API data, here is my full gist atm, I need to iterate the `i` inside of the `tweetArrayObj` but that's the least of my problems. https://gist.github.com/leongaban/d5f119bd39ca213c7c45

Comment: It seems that you really need an event when all promises finished, because now you are drawing chart in a loop. I guess you want to collect all data and then draw a chart?

Comment: Yes I need to wait till `tweetArrayObjsContainer` is filled, then push it into `chartObj.chartData` then draw the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Put every promise in an array then do:

```
$q.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(){
  // this runs when every promise is resolved.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using deferreds is widely considered to be an anti-pattern. If your promise library supports a promise contstructor, that's an easier way to create your own promises.

Rather than trying to resolve all of the promises in one, I usually use a promise implementation that has an `all` function. Then I create one function that returns a promise for a thing, and then another function that returns a promise for all the things.

Using a `map()` function is also usually a lot cleaner than using a `for` loop.

Here's a generic recipe. Assuming your promise implementation has some flavor of an `all` function:

```
var fetchOne = function(oneData){
 //Use a library that returns a promise
 return ajax.get("http://someurl.com/" + oneData);
};

var fetchAll = function(allData){
  //map the data onto the promise-returning function to get an
  //array of promises. You could also use `_.map` if you're a 
  //lodash or underscore user.
  var allPromises = myData.map(fetchOne);
  return Promise.all(allPromises);
};

var allData = ["a", "b", "c"];
var promiseForAll = fetchAll(allData);

//Handle the results for all of the promises.
promiseForAll.then(function(results){
  console.log("All done.", results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to this question and the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996362/) :

- the code in general will be a lot cleaner with [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in lieu of `for` loops, in several places.
- `getTagQuotes()` will be made cleaner by building an array of promises, submitting it to `$q.all()` and returning an aggregate promise.
- `formatTagData()`, and its relationship with its caller, will be made cleaner by returning the transformed `rawData`.

With a few assumptions, the code should simplify to something like this :

```
getTagQuotes(tags).then(function(tweetArrayObjsContainer) {
    chartObj.chartData = chartObj.chartData.concat(tweetArrayObjsContainer); // concat() ...
    // chartObj.chartData = tweetArrayObjsContainer;                         // ... or simply assign??
    chartDirective = ScopeFactory.getScope('chart');
    chartDirective.nvd3.drawChart(chartObj.chartData);
});

function getTagQuotes(tags) {
    var url = 'app/api/social/twitter/volume/';
    var promises = tags.map(function(tag) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol(url + tag.term_id)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            console.log(tag.term_id + ': error in returning tweet data');
            deferred.resolve(null); // resolve() here effectively catches the error
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    });
    return $q.all(promises).then(formatTagData); //this is much much cleaner than building an explicit data array and resolving an outer deferred.

    function formatTagData(rawData) {
        return rawData.filter(function(data) {
            return data || false; // filter out any nulls
        }).map(function(item, i) {
            return {
                'key': 'Quantity' + (i+1),
                'type': 'area',
                'yAxis': 1,
                'color': tagColorArray[i],
                'values': item.frequency_counts.reverse().map(function(c) {
                    return {
                        x: addZeroes(c.start_epoch),
                        y: c.tweets,
                    };
                })
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I just tried this out.. but looks like I'll need to add another promise chain inside of my `returnTweetVol` function as well now.

Comment: That sounds like (part of?) a good idea. Ideally, `returnTweetVol()` will return a promise such that you can write `GetTweetVolFactory.returnTweetVol(url + tag.term_id).then(...)`, avoiding the need to promisify on-the-fly, as in my answer.